# JQuery CSS conflict

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the datepicker which renders incorrectly on my webpage. The date rows have a white outline when I roll over them. The jquery index.html test page ok as does my webpage when I comment out my existing CSS.

I have looked at the Jquery and as most of it is prefixed by "ui." there shouldn't be a problem. I've gone through the structure of the widget using Firebug looking for conflicts and have managed to find and clear a conflict on 'thead' tags. But I'm struggling to find any more. I suspect its a 'tr' or 'td' tag.

(I'm a bit surprised that not all the tags used by the widget have their own classes.)

I was going to go into the jquery code and see if I can add classes to the td and tr tags and then change the css to ignore any other formatting from attached CSSs. However, before I do that, is there an easier / better way of dealing with CSS conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your stylesheet, force your properties with !important;

```
td:hover{
border-color:black !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pixeline. I have complex CSSs that I've inherited. I tried your approach and while it definitely is the right way to go, it still requires investigation work to know exactly which reference is causing the problem. For example, in my case it was a reference "tbody tr:hover td". Also, forcing that the style impacted on my webpage so I had black borders on my tables.
Cheers
ALJ